# Use a local package index before PyPi

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Is there a way to make `pip` look at a local package repository *first* (i.e. before it looks in PyPi)?

I have a local package named `pydxl` (a package for working with IBM DOORS DXL scripts). Previously I could install with

```
pip install -f //my/local/repo pydxl
```

Which was fine. As of a few days ago there is a package on PyPi that has the same name! So the above command installs that package by default.
Ok, so if I use

```
pip install --no-index -f //my/local/repo pydxl
```

that gets **my** package, but now does not install the dependencies (such as Jinja) from PyPi.

What I would like is something like "look at my local index FIRST, and then look at PyPI". Is this ordering possible?

Comment: Try `pip install --index-url=/my/local/repo --extra-index-url=https://pypi.org/simple pydxl`